# USDZ Objects appearing tiny

Tags: blender, maya, arkit, usdz

When exporting as USDZ on multiple files we have an issue where an item that is 85cm high in Blender is appearing as about 5mm high in AR view.

Steps taken:

- Exported as both abc and obj
- Tried multiple objects
- Tried multiple variations of textures and files
- Is accurately scaled in our 3D software

You can download the USDZ generated and the raw files here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HTcVxaMiWnJJyEhIaMdo5nc_jt49kXsd?usp=sharing

[Blender Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2pyD.png)

[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZQzx.png)

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks, Allen

Comment: Two things to check, Is the scale of your object 1.0? You should [apply the scale](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html#apply) so it is 1.0. Is the unit scale in your [scene units settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/scenes/properties.html#units) at 1.0? This will change your measurements but not the exported size. Also some exporters have a scale option, this may be resizing during export.

Comment: hi @sambler it seems our dimensions were correct but obj only deals with units which we had set to 0.85 after reading that it was measured in meters. It seems however that a blender unit is one centimetre. We were basically 100x off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though dimensions were correct and some forum posts equated 1 unit in Blender to 1 meter, it was actually 1cm. For others please export with this in mind. <3